# Norm is multiplicative?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ideals

Let $L/K$ be a finite extension of *number fields*. Let $I$ be an ideal in $L$, we define the norm $N(I)$ of $I$ to be the ideal in $K$ generated by elements of the type $N_{L|K}(a)$ where $a \in I.$ I want to show that $N$ is multiplicative. I am able to show that $N(I)N(J) \subseteq N(IJ)$ because, elements in $N(I)$ looks like $\sum r_i N(a_i)$ where $a_i \in I,$

So if $x=\sum_i r_iN(a_i), a_i \in I$ and $y= \sum_j s_j N(b_j), b_j \in J$ then $$xy = \sum \sum r_i s_j N(a_i b_j) \in N(IJ).$$
So $$N(I)N(J) \subseteq N(IJ).$$

What is not clear to me is the other direction. Since, norm is not additive in general, it is not clear to me how to prove this.

Note : Ideals in $L$ means ideals in the ring of integers of $L.$

Comment: There are no nontrivial ideals in a field. Can you please clarify how $I$ is defined?

Comment: Usually, ideals in $\mathcal{O}_L$ are considered, i.e., in the ring of integers of $L$.

Comment: @EugeneKogan It looks like you are unfamiliar with the concept of ring of integers in a number field, as a matter of resources, you can look at any standard textbooks of Algebraic number theory such as Lang or Neukirch

Comment: I do not understand why there is a downvote and a vote to close this question, it would be more appropriate to the downvoter to explain the same.

Comment: @EugeneKogan As Dietrich Burde noted above, it is a convention in the subject to call ideals in ring of integers as ideals in the field.

Comment: @3f183201 Sorry, you are correct. The question looks entirely valid to me now.

Comment: @3f183201 I also have no idea about the downvote and the close vote. In the past weeks this has become too common on MSE. Anyway: good question, 1+.

Comment: The terminology overload for "ideal in $K$" is unfortunate, though, even though it is common in the literature on the subject. I suggest to write $\mathcal{O}_L$ and $\mathcal{O}_K$ in the question just to avoid any misunderstanding.

Comment: Random thought: have you tried to use prime decomposition of ideals? Also, do you know how to prove the special case $J=I$?

Comment: A more general formulation is that $N_{L/K}$ is a group homomorphism $\mathcal{I}_{\mathcal{O}_L}\to\mathcal{I}_{\mathcal{O}_K}$ between ideal groups (see [ideal norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_norm)). And it's worth noting both ideal groups are free abelian groups. A detailed proof of this more general statement using completions can be found in Cassels&Frohlich pp.14-16. If $L/K$ is Galois, a simplified proof using Galois group may be found in p.151, IV.6.5 of Lorenzini's [book](https://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-9/)

Answer (score 2):

*Localize*.  Prove the norm map on ideals commutes with localization at prime ideals:
$$
{\rm N}_{\mathcal O_L/\mathcal O_K}(I)\mathcal O_{K,\mathfrak p}
= 
{\rm N}_{\mathcal O_{L,\mathfrak p}/\mathcal O_{K,\mathfrak p}}(I\mathcal O_{L,\mathfrak p}) 
$$
for all nonzero prime ideals $\mathfrak p$ in $\mathcal O_L$.

Thus proving that
$$
{\rm N}_{\mathcal O_L/\mathcal O_K}(IJ) = {\rm N}_{\mathcal O_L/\mathcal O_K}(I){\rm N}_{\mathcal O_L/\mathcal O_K}(J)
$$
where $I$ and $J$ are two (nonzero) ideals in $\mathcal O_L$
is equivalent proving that
$$
{\rm N}_{\mathcal O_{L,\mathfrak p}/\mathcal O_{K,\mathfrak p}}(I\mathcal O_{L,\mathfrak p}J\mathcal O_{L,\mathfrak p}) = 
{\rm N}_{\mathcal O_{L,\mathfrak p}/\mathcal O_{K,\mathfrak p}}(I\mathcal O_{L,\mathfrak p}){\rm N}_{\mathcal O_{L,\mathfrak p}/\mathcal O_{K,\mathfrak p}}(J\mathcal O_{L,\mathfrak p})
$$
for all nonzero prime ideals $\mathfrak p$ in $\mathcal O_L$.
At this level of generality, you should aim to prove a more general result:
$$
{\rm N}_{\mathcal O_{L,\mathfrak p}/\mathcal O_{K,\mathfrak p}}(\mathfrak a\mathfrak b) = 
{\rm N}_{\mathcal O_{L,\mathfrak p}/\mathcal O_{K,\mathfrak p}}(\mathfrak a){\rm N}_{\mathcal O_{L,\mathfrak p}/\mathcal O_{K,\mathfrak p}}(\mathfrak b)
$$
for all nonzero ideals $\mathfrak a$ and $\mathfrak b$ in $\mathcal O_{L,\mathfrak p}$. That is, prove the norm map on ideals in $\mathcal O_{L,\mathfrak p}$ is multiplicative.

The advantage of the latter equation is that the base ring $\mathcal O_{K,\mathfrak p}$ is a DVR and $\mathcal O_{L,\mathfrak p}$ is a PID with finitely many prime ideals, so all ideals in $\mathcal O_{L,\mathfrak p}$ are principal.